# How to fix too large logo?

Tags: author, logos

I used the Springer Template to build my paper.

https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940

The template does not have a place for orcid so I added it in my LaTeX. Here is the code:

```
\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{My Title Here}

\author*[1]{\fnm{Name} \sur{Surname} \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}\email{myemail@hh.co}
```

The problem is that the orcid logo is too big

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: There is more than one "Springer Template". Please be more specific as to which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico here is the template : https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the class file we can see

```
\gdef\orcidlogo{%
\includegraphics{Orcidlogo.eps}%
}%

\gdef\orcid#1{\href{#1}{\orcidlogo}}%
```

On the other hand, the ZIP file has no trace of `Orcidlogo.eps`, so you need to supply your own. And the best thing to do is to redefine `\orcidlogo` in the document.

**<rant mode>**

The `sn-jnl.cls` that comes with the ZIP file you link to has

```
\ProvidesClass{sn-jnl}
              [2019/11/18 v0.1: An authoring template for Springer Journal articles]
```

but it is significantly different from a previous version bearing the same exact information. In particular, the present version lacks the call to some packages that the class itself *does* employ, namely `manyfoot`, `xcolor` and `amsmath`. You *must* load them in your document or it wouldn't compile.

**</rant mode>**

I downloaded a suitable icon from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ORCID_iD.svg), namely the 240px version. Now the test document can be, after also redefining `\orcid` to actually provide a URL,

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\orcidlogo}{%
  \includegraphics[width=10pt]{240px-ORCID_iD.svg.png}%
}
\renewcommand{\orcid}{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\orcidlogo}}

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{My Title Here}

\author*[1]{\fnm{Name} \sur{Surname} \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}\email{myemail@hh.co}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the ORCID logo, open the sn-jnl.cls file with your LaTeX editor, go to the end of the file, where you will find the

```
\gdef\orcidlogo{%    
\includegraphics{Orcidlogo.eps}%    
}%
```

function defined.

Now all you have to do is add your desired size to the `\includegraphics` command; e.g, like this:

```
\gdef\orcidlogo{%    
\includegraphics[width=3mm]{Orcidlogo.eps}%    
}%
```

Comment: It is not good advice to ask the user to alter a `cls` especially if then indent to send the article to others can do not have the altered version of the cls. If needed redefine the macro in the preamble of the article.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `cls` in this case is defined in such a way that no macro in the article's preamble can change the size of the image. So the only alternative route for the user is to change the size of the logo image by hand.

Comment: What do you think happen if you move that redefinition into the OPs article? It has the same effect as if the OP had added it to the cls.

Comment: Could you write a detailed answer to the OP's question that explicitly implements your suggestion? I am curious how that would work.

Comment: Exactly what egreg answered