# Issue with \documentclass{sn-jnl}

Tags: documentclass, springer

If I try to compile with pdflatex (or just latex) the following simple code (sn-jnl.cls is the documentclass for Springer journals, so I assume it is widely used...)

---

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    
\title{My Title}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction} 

My Intro

\end{document}
```

I get error message

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
```

and, if I look into the log file I read (at some point):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ->\SetFootnoteHook 
                                         {\hspace *{-8pt}}\DeclareNewFootnot...
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...8pt}}\DeclareNewFootnote 
                                                  {A}[gobble]\setlength {\sk...
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \skip \footinsA 
                           
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...}}}{}\allowdisplaybreaks 
                                                  \Gm@savelength {paperwidth...
l.5 \begin{document}
                    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Indeed, in sn-jnl.cls you can read the lines

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
%%\newcommand*\ExtraParaSkip{12pt}%
\SetFootnoteHook{\hspace*{-8pt}}%
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[gobble]%
\setlength{\skip\footinsA}{0pt}}%
```

I do not understand the problem here.

I downloaded sn-jnl.cls from Springer website.

I am with MikTeX on MacOS.

Thanks
Maurizio

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the same as in [How to fix too large logo?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/692157/4427).

The class developers decided to avoid loading all packages the previous version of the class did, but so doing they also removed the packages the class itself depends on. And they didn't even change the version number!

Solution:

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

My Intro

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You are forced to add the packages which sn-jnl does not load by itself:

```
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Frankly, I think that this from Springer is terrible....

Do you know if this has been fixed in some release of the documentclass (but I downloaded it from Springer website...) ???

Thanks

Maurizio